# Intersections of all open subsets of finite index in the idele group

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. Why is the intersections of all open subgroups of finite index in the idele group $\mathbb I_K$ equal to $\overline{K^{\times}(K^{\times}_{\infty})^0}$? Also, I'm having a hard time thinking about $\overline{K^{\times}(K^{\times}_{\infty})^0}$: how much larger is the closure?

(EDIT: As David Loeffler writes, we need to consider subgroups of finite index containing $K^{\times}$.)

Here, 
$$
(K_\infty^{\times})^0:=\prod_{v\text{ real}}\mathbb R_{>0}\times \prod_{v\text{ complex}}\mathbb C\times \prod_{v\in V_K^0} 1.
$$
where $V_K^0$ is the set of finite places of $K$.

(I'll refer to my notes for the standard definitions and statements, http://web.mit.edu/~holden1/www/math/ant.pdf, 10.5.1 for $\mathbb I_K$, 10.5.4 for the embedding $K^{\times}\hookrightarrow \mathbb I_K$.)

**Context:** 
This question comes up when trying to prove [p.263] the topological isomorphism [10.6.5] $ G(K^{\text{ab}}/K)\cong \mathbb I_K/\overline{K^{\times}(K^{\times}_{\infty})^0}$ ("1-dimensional Langlands") from the usual statement of global class field theory [10.6.1].

Given that the map is surjective, it remains to show the kernel is $\overline{K^{\times}(K^{\times}_{\infty})^0}$, which will follow (from the existence theorem) if it is the intersection of all open subsets of finite index in $\mathbb I_K$.

Comment: There is something fishy going on here because not every finite-index subgroup of $\mathbf{I}_K$ will contain $K^\times$ (e.g. take the subgroup of all elements whose $v$-adic valuation is even, for $v$ your favourite finite place of $K$). You want the intersection of all open subgroups of finite index *containing $K^\times$*. Note that any such subgroup also contains $(K_\infty^\times)^\circ$, so you're reduced to showing that the closure of a certain subgroup is the intersection of the finite-index subgroups containing it, which is pretty much immediate from the definition of the topology.